# HTML5 best framework for animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

(sorry for my english)

I can't belive the only way for animations on canvas is the 'setInterval()'
somebody know better?
setInterval is too slow and its work bad with old devices.

Comment: “animations on **canvas** ” “its work bad with **old devices** ” What did you expect?

Comment: i think a device with core 2 can more than a rotating with 10 balls.

Comment: @BenCTaylor Those aren't old devices.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS3 animations and transitions.
Most modern browsers will hardware accelerate them; they will be much faster than anything you can write in Javascript.

If your animations are too complicated for pure CSS, use `requestAnimationFrame()`, which will allow your animations to run at the browser frame rate and avoid unnecessary computation.

Comment: 'Animations on canvas' I'm pretty sure you can't use CSS on the canvas element.

Comment: Well except from styling the borders and background.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995: That's why I added the last paragraph.  Using straight DOM elements with pure CSS may be faster.

Comment: CSS3 animations (where applicable) are great. You actually tell the browser you want an animation in a way it understands, rather than shoving interval calculations down its throat every 16ms :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`. It often works smoother.

Comment: I'd highly reccommend moving to `requestAnimationFrame()`. Here is a great polyfill for older browsers: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/. It can seem like a strange work-flow at first but the performance benefits on browsers that support the API is something that shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: You learn something every day. :)